# Atom IDE - Beautify JSX formatting

Tags: atom-editor, atom-beautify

I've seen other questions about Atom IDE here so I figured I would ask. If there is a more relevant place to post a question like this let me know and I'll take it down and move it.

I'm using Atom with the package Atom Beautify. I'm creating JSX files and when I run beautify the formatting doesn't follow JSX standards for component props, it makes it really hard to read.

How do I get it to format as displayed below?

Example: `Desired setting`

```
<SingleInput 
  inputType={'text'} 
  controlFunc={this.handleQualificationNameChange(qualification.uniqueId)} 
  content={qualification.qualification} 
  placeholder={'Qualification'} 
  bsSize={null}
/>
```

Example: `Current setting`

```
<SingleInput inputType={'text'} controlFunc={this.handleQualificationNameChange(qualification.uniqueId)} content={qualification.qualification} placeholder={'Qualification'} bsSize={null}/>
```